# Failed to resolve a lot of android libraries?

Tags: android, kotlin

I faced recently after the last android update a lot of errors due to implementing libraries that i used to work with in my other apps before and I can't find a solution for the problem.[image: example of problem when implemnting library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
        ...
     maven {
       url 'https://jitpack.io'
     }
   }
}
```

try this and ReBuild Project

method 2
Clear Caches and restart Android studio

Hopefully this is worked for you

Comment: the problem is that i wasn't adding the jitpack below all projects, thnx bro

Comment: 1. On header menu got to ->Files
2. Then Click On invalid cache/Restart    try this

Answer (score 1):

Did you add maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } in your build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem not there am already using jitpack google() and jcenter()

Comment: Share gradle details.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
 allprojects {
  repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
 }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
// Material Components for Android
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.github.ImaginativeShohag:Oops-No-Internet:v1.1.5'
}
```

Sync the gradle and check.

Comment: i already add the jitpack, google() and jcenter() the problem is not there i think, because there are a few libraries works fine but a lot of others don't